# Saving downloaded File to custom folder

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Using Downloadmanager method for downloading file from firestore. When files are downloaded, its saved inside the APP root folder inside the phones(Android-data-com.app.).But instead i need to save  the file in to a custom folder in phones memory. What changes should i make in below code.

I have given code for read-write permission in manifest.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Downloadsviewholder downloadsviewholder, final int i) {
        downloadsviewholder.dName.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getName());
        downloadsviewholder.dUploaddate.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getUploaddate());
        downloadsviewholder.dExtension.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getFileextension());
        Picasso.get().load(downloadsmodels.get(i).getIcon()).into(downloadsviewholder.dIcon);
        downloadsviewholder.dButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ConnectionCheck.checkconnetion(download_activity)) {
                    dowloadFile(downloadsviewholder.dName.getContext(), downloadsmodels.get(i).getName(), downloadsmodels.get(i).getFileextension()
                            , DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, downloadsmodels.get(i).getLink());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(download_activity,"Check your internet connection",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void dowloadFile (Context context,String filename, String fileextension, String destinationdirectory, String url){

        DownloadManager downloadManager=(DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationdirectory,filename+"."+fileextension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }
```

Comment: `inside the APP root folder inside the phones(Android-data-com.app.)`. No root folder. Inside getExternalFilesDir() you mean. See your code: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context`.

Comment: You should first tell full path of that custom folder. Also tell full path that you used now.